# foreach save to mysqli

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

This is make me so confusing,
I can't save my form to my database orderly.

Please see the image below.
form image
[image]

The database EXAMPLE save only...

[image: example db]

so when you see it its not 1, 2,3,4 but on the image was 1,3,2,4
how can i save it orderly?

HTML CODE

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="computation_table">
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Categorie&euml;n</th>
    <th>Aantal</th>
    <th>Omschrijving</th>
    <th>Bedrag</th>
    <th>Totaal</th>
    <th>BTW</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <a id="add_new_element"><img src="images/add.png" width="20" alt="add product" /></a> 
    <a id="add_new_category"><img src="images/cat.png" alt="add category" /></a>
    </td>
    <td align="left" colspan="6">
        <input type="text" name="input[0][cat_name]" style="font-weight:bold;" value="Categorie naam" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <a id="add_new_element"><img src="images/add.png" width="20" alt="add product" /></a>
    <a id="add_new_category"><img src="images/cat.png" alt="add category" /></a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="input[0][category]" class="text_com" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="input[0][quantity]" id="new_quan" class="quantity text_com" value="" /> x
    </td>
    <td width="180">
        <textarea name="input[0][quo_definition]" class="input"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="input[0][quo_amt]" id="new_amt" class="quantity text_com" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td id="total">
        <span id="view_total_0">0</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="input[0][quo_total]" id="new_total" class="quantity text_com" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="input[0][quo_btw]" class="btwselect">
            <option value="21%" selected="selected">21%</option>
            <option value="6%">6%</option>
            <option value="0%">0%</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<div class="ClientProductItemsSubTotal">
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td><strong>Korting</strong></td><td><input type="text" name="discount" class="quantity" value="" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

form to DB `$input = array();`

```
foreach( $_POST['input'] as $input ) {
$mysqli->query( "INSERT INTO jon_com_quo_computation VALUE('', '$uc', '$cc', '$ct', '$cur', '', '".$input['cat_name']."', '".$input['category']."', '".$input['quantity']."', '".$input['quo_definition']."', '".$input['quo_amt']."', '".$input['quo_total']."', '".$input['quo_btw']."', '$dis', '', '', '1', 'new', NOW() )" );
}
```

jQuery to add form below... which should be in bottom... i used `.insertAfter(rowfield);`

```
jQuery(function() {    
id = 0;
jQuery('a#add_new_element').live('click', function() {
id++;

var rowfield = jQuery(this).parent().parent();//add some .parent() untill you get the TR element
jQuery('<tr><td><a id="add_new_element"><img src="images/add.png" width="20" alt="add product" /></a> <a id="add_new_category"><img src="images/cat.png" alt="add category" /></a></td><td><input type="text" name="input['+id+'][category]" class="text_com" value="" /></td><td><input type="text" name="input['+id+'][quantity]" id="new_quan" class="quantity" value="" /> x</td><td width="200"><textarea name="input['+id+'][quo_definition]" class="input"></textarea></td><td><input type="text" name="input['+id+'][quo_amt]" id="new_amt" class="quantity" value="0" /></td><td><span id="view_total_'+id+'">0</span><input type="hidden" id="new_total" name="input['+id+'][quo_total]" class="quantity" value="0" /></td><td><select name="input['+id+'][quo_btw]" class="btwselect"><option value="21%" selected="selected">21%</option><option value="6%">6%</option><option value="0%">0%</option></select></td><td><a id="del_row"><img src="images/del.png" class="DelRow" alt="delete" /></a></td></tr>').insertAfter(rowfield);

});
```

thank you so much for your share ideas....

Edited: for more explanation...
There are two things that i need to fixed.
First is that when it save to my database the orderly is not really that follow.
It should be `a b c d` not `a c b d`

Second thing is that I am not sure if im going to use `insertAfter()` or `insertBefore()`
What my boss want is that, he can add any form --when he click the add button it should be add below.

For example when i click the green + add button it should add to the last tr that already added.

I am open to explain more..

Comment: good lord, i'm confused as well!

Comment: im so sorry if my english is so confusing too... let me edit it and put some more explaination...

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."

Comment: id must be unique , its wrong to have id="add_new_element"  more than once use class instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use append instead of insertAfter in your click event:

```
var $table = jQuery(this).closest('table')
$table.append('<tr>whatever</tr>');
```

Comment: hi Mr. @HarryFink Thank you so much, append was working fine now. My god my post was too long and the only answer was simple T_T I need more experience to be like you sir.

Comment: And I try it to my DB->Save it is now orderly save im so happy... thanks again @HarryFink

Comment: By the way use class name instead of id, because id should be unique in the html document. And also consider replace live() with on()